# "Close a day" on calendar: prevent new item creation on a day

Tags: list, calendar, newform

I need to add a way to prevent new item creation on a chosen day, after this day has been somehow selected.
We use a calendar for Resource Booking. The approver wants to be able to "close" a day when he knows for this particular day there are no other resources available.

My first idea was to create an all-day event called "Day is closed" on this day and check before the approval workflow starts if there is such an event on this day, but unfortunately I cannot search for this event on this day in a WF.

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thank you in advance!